# Will Ubuntu 20.02 run on Intel Core 2 Duo E8400 (2) @ 3.000GHz and 160GB of hardisk

Tags: boot, intel

I have a desktop of Intel core 2 and its a 64bit machine. Will ubuntu 20.02 run without any trouble? Thanks!

Comment: Firstly there was no Ubuntu release in 2020-Feburary (ie. 20.02, Ubuntu releases are *year.month* in format showing the release date).  I use a dell [optiplex] 755 (c2d-e8300, 8gb, amd/ati radeon rv610/radeon hd2400 pro/xt) for testing purposes, and it runs all releases including unreleased *groovy* (though I prefer flavors myself)

Comment: Please is 8gb ram?

Comment: Sorry yeah, I use the format  "brand [name] model (cpu, ram, video)" with all details coming from `lshw` (or list hardware).  I also use boxes with less ram, that just happened to be the closest CPU to yours, eg.  another is "dell [optiplex] 755 (c2d-e6850, 5gb, amd/ati radeon rv516/x1300/x1550)"  - but I have 25 on the list used in testing..

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 20.04 will run on your configuration. but might be possible slow performance you will get.

Because 20.04 version has heavy graphics and animations.

I hope this answer will help you.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 20.02.

Comment: 20.\* I don't think is any better. Why not provide the correct release name (the only other release for this year is still in development, thus is called *groovy* currently, as it'll only get it's *year.month* format name on actual release.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Thank you very much.